# what does "overcompensation" mean?

Tags: capacitor, power-factor-correction

I read that using fixed capacitors in power factor correction in low voltage has some disadvantages like : Overcompensation (correct past unity)
can someone explain that to me?

Comment: Varying load with fixed compensation.

Answer (score 1):

Compensation for power factor means adding some capacitive reactance to compensate for the usual inductive reactance.

Fixed capacitors means that you may have to pick certain discrete values so you can decide to leave the load as somewhat inductive (undercompensated) or capacitive (overcompensated). If the load inductance varies during operation  then again you may have to pick some intermediate value and the cancellation may be fairly imperfect.

Answer (score 0):

Inductive loads increase ZL(f) impedance with rising f.

C loads decreases Zc(f) with rising f.

Thus over compensating is over.oading the voltage source with a reactive load that raises the VAR power above real power with more current and more **conduction losses** than under-compensating at the same <1 p.f.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f79vJ8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

ZL(50Hz) is not always same as load R , but is for this simple example.

But what is |Zc(50Hz)| at PF=1 Answer: same as |ZL(50Hz)| magnitude.

But what is impedance for 1Khz or 1us risetime with line reclosure of cap?
Answer:? Depends on ESR.

what if ESR was 10 uOhm Polyester?
But what if switch was after L for reclose Line. ( really bad)

Comment: but the capacitor (parallel to load) is used to give the load kvars without the need of kvars of the source so in case of overcompensation the capacitor will give more kvars to load and the source won't be affected that's what i understand..now how overcompensation over load the source ?

Comment: OK let me try to explain using Admittance known Spectrum to step response for a switched AC ON.

Comment: Lines are usually like 2000 uH/km not henries but transformers and motor loads can be very high

Comment: 3mF rack mounted line caps can absorb 50kAmps on switched voltage on line. YOu dont want to add more than necessary and use line impedance to limit surge current.

Comment: aha so the residual  kvars that capcitors give aren't for free it costs current  from the line so Q+ must equal Q- to not absorb core current am i right ?

Comment: yes and no. Surge currents on reconnect depend where the surge is relative to PFC and transformer remenance.  Incorrectly placed PFC can adding more voltage dip on dV/dt start and current rise. So it stresses Ic=C dV/dt after which steady state it does balance reactive I, so then no penalty,it helps. So they always under compensate PFC slightly. (tradeoff with cost too) If core gets saturated from remenance and DCR, thus big L becomes small DCR on startup, primary excitation currents are huge. Meaning they always need reliable reactors in series to any fault or reclosure switch to limit Ipk